# Activities on multiple displays in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors

I have 2 external monitors attached to my laptop and have the Primary Display set to be the built-in laptop display. That has the top bar, as I'd expect, but the Activities are appearing to the left of monitor 2, when I would expect them to also be on the primary display. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You should be able to go into settings and select which monitor (or all monitors) should display the Activities bar.

Comment: Yes, that should work but doesn't. It sets the top bar on the correct screen but not the Activities bar

Answer (score 0):

My solution: install 'Dash to Dock' Gnome extension

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

In the settings of it you can choose on which monitor the dock is shown.

Comment: After the second lock, the dock was displayed on the locked screen. I removed 'Dash to Dock', and after that the standard dash worked normally. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was the Appearance tab in the settings, as described in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1400955