# How to move Ubuntu top bar to primary monitor (Ubuntu 20.04)?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, workspaces, gnome-session

How does one move the Ubuntu top bar (and also the alt-tab and workspaces popups) to the primary monitor?

I have managed to get the Ubuntu dock to the primary monitor by fiddling with dconf.

Nevertheless, the top bar, alt-tab popup, and workspaces popups persist in appearing only on the secondary monitor, not only after specifying the primary monitor but also through re-logon and reboot.

Comment: This should happen automatically for the display that is set as the primary display. Are your monitor settings in "Display" correct, i.e., is the primary monitor as you see there effectively the one you expect to be the primary?

Comment: Let's see... if memory serves me... you move the top bar/panel in the Display settings, and if memory serves me... option-drag the top bar/panel from one display to the other display. If it's not option, try other keys like control, etc.

Comment: Adjusting the primary monitor settings in the Nvidia X Server Settings GUI app did the trick.  GNOME Settings and Tweaks, not so much.  The boot sequence and GRUB menu continue to be displayed only on the secondary monitor, however.  One imagines that's a video BIOS issue, however.  Getting a fresh 20.04/GNOME3 install working is another ring of hell, so that issue is way down the list.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug.  Still exist in version 22.

Open your SETTINGS

There are two locations.

1. "Appearance" which lets you decide which monitor to show the Dock on (if any).
2. "Displays" which let's you adjust your display settings and list Primary Display.

I have found, that setting this will often cause the other to revert or display incorrectly.

Here is what works for me...

1. I make sure they are both set to the default monitor.
2. I change the Displays to make my big monitor the primary, the APPLY. Once I do that, I then adjust the 'Primary Display' as well as the "Appearance" to be the way I want.  Once set, it should stay that way as long as you don't have a monitor frequency issue.

Comment: Hello. If you are saying there is a Ubuntu version 22 there is no such thing. If you are referring to 22.04 it does not exist yet and is off topic till released.

Comment: Yeah, my bad.  I was thinking of the year.  It's actually Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 1):

Just facing the same problem in

Try changing the Primary Display configuration in the "Displays" Settings

Here's the clue:

[ubuntu 22.04 display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgqnW.png)